# cache Flask-Login user_loader

Tags: session, caching, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

We use `flask-login` and from the code it seems that the `user_loader` callback is called on *every single request*. I understand that it is to load the current user but can I circumvent hitting the users table for every request ?

here's how my user loader looks like

```
@login_manager.user_loader
 def load_user(id=None):
  return User.query.get(id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `User.query.get` that should be cached instead of `load_user`

This is a sample code:

`def get_user(id):
    if not id:
         return None
    cache_key = 'user_%d' % id
    rt = cache.get(cache_key)
    if rt is not None:  # cache hitten
        return rt
    else:  # cache miss
        u = User.query.get(id)
        cache.set(cache_key, u)
        return u`

Some notes:

1. Here the `cache` object represent a redis client or memcached client, that leaves you to implement.
2. Also user instance may not be stored in cache backend directly, so
   serialization and deserialization should be done.
3. You should also check cache result's expire time if necessary.
4. Next but not the least, when user got changed (attribute edited or state updated e.g.), cache should be invoked.
5. The cache pattern (return if cache hitten, get and cache if cache miss) can be implemented as a cache decorator so can be reused for other types' caching.

Comment: I feel so silly after reading the first line of your answer, that it didn't occur to me before asking ! thanks @menghan